# How to keep an download url given for a user valid for a minute , once the time is elapsed, the web app should redirect to error page

Tags: java, web-applications, security

I want to provide a url to an requested user through email for a download request. The url is valid for a minutes, when user tries to access that url after a minutes the web app should redirect him to another page. what is the best logic to go about!!.kindly let me know your views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an URL to the resource to download that contains a query string with an encrypted expiration date. Very simple to manage and you don't have to rely on a database.

http://example.com/download.php?aid=jHYgIK7d

Comment: i didnt understand.kindly explain the flow.

Comment: One pragmatic way to tell a download page when it expired is to pass it the information in the query string. However you don't want the user to know how to set himself the expiration, so you encrypt it.

Comment: but how do u know while file to download ,when the querystring is just an encrypted timestamp.somewhere we need to have relation with encrypted value and the file.

Answer (score 2):

1. Generate a large random string (GUID)
2. Write this string with the timestamp to a database
3. Give the user a link to /download?guid=[your guid]
4. Write a servlet and map it to /download
5. in your servlet

5.1. Read the GUID from the request parameter

5.2. check the database that the time is still valid

5.3. if yes, read the file from your server and stream it from the servlet to the user (make sure to set the content type correctly)

5.4. update the db-table to indicate that this GUID was already used

5.3' if not, redirect to error page

Comment: Need the alternative use case for the invalid request as well :)

Comment: @Levy thanks but for an invalid request.is it possible without hitting database.

Comment: Pierre's idea is nice as well.

Comment: @Suresh. Use Pierre's idea for initial validation of the timestamp. Pass both timestamp and guid. If the timestamp is valid, query the database (and re-check the time stamp) and the deliver the file (or not).

Comment: passing timestamp means currenttimestamp when url is created, and then when the url is accessed (current timestamp - passed one) >  10 seconds , then redirect to invalid page.